# Rails 3 - time_ago_in_words says "ABOUT 2 hours ago"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Code:

```
<%="#{time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)} ago "%>
```

What i'd like is for it not to have "ABOUT" in front of the 2 hours ago, which shows up for hours but not for minutes...

Is there another function or a way to remove it without finding and replacing?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can change this via your I18n locale file.  In config/locales/en.yml...

```
"en":
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      about_x_hours:
        # The defaults are "about 1 hour" and "about %{count} hours"
        one: "1 hour"
        other: "%{count} hours"
```

See the [default locale file in actionpack](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/locale/en.yml#L18) for a complete reference.

Comment: Actually, this would give wrong output. For instance `helper.distance_distance_of_time_in_words(1.hour+29.minutes)` would with this solution output "1 hour", and if you add one minute, it would output "2 hours". That's why it's called "about 1 hour" and "about 2 hours" originally. It uses time intervals based on rounding up and down to determine what the nearest full hour or similar is. I suggest using the dotiw gem instead, for precise times. https://github.com/radar/dotiw

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue, I ended up doing this, mostly because I'm still up in the air about whether or not to remove the about globally -

```
<p class="entry_created_at"><%= time_ago_in_words(plate.created_at).gsub('about','') + ' ago' %></p>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use my [dotiw](http://github.com/radar/dotiw) gem/plugin for that. It adds a couple of additional options and has greater precision than the one Rails offers.

```
distance_of_time_in_words(time1, time2, :only => [:days, :hours, :minutes])
```

Comment: thxs, but I like the lack of precision for the app I'm building.. It's more about removing the word "about" make sense?

Comment: @TheApprentice, well in that case use the `:vague` option in dotiw.

Comment: @AnApprentice: This should be the accepted answer, as the answer from Dave actually will give the wrong/unintended output.