# Rails how to shorten time_ago_in_words

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails newbie question. Currently I have an app that includes:

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago.
```

This produces output similar to:

"6 days, 21 hours, and 56 minutes ago."

I'd like to simplify and generalize this a bit to be more like:

"6 days ago" or "5 hours ago" or "A few seconds ago" etc

1. How can I do this?
2. I noticed in the Hartl rails tutorial that the `<%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>` works as intended (i.e. short and sweet). Why the difference? Is `time_ago_in_words` output dependent on rails version used?

Comment: Which version of rails do you use? According to apidock (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words) it should return the "short" version.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801324/rails-3-time-ago-in-words-says-about-2-hours-ago

Comment: Tessi - I'm running Rails 3.0.20 (plan to update soon, but will take time since the app I'm working on is live) Arjan - Saw this link before I posted, but want to ask the community about this specific case before I mess with the I18n locale file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helper method `time_ago_in_words` is just a wrapper of `distance_of_time_in_words` by sending argument `to_time` to fixed `Time.now`.

If you are not ready to upgrade, you can try to copy the `distance_of_time_in_words` method of Rails 3.2.13 directly into your ApplicationHelper.

I can't verify that since I don't have your version. But it worth a trial.

The source is here, thanks to link provided by tessi: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words

Answer (score 0):

I know you can remove the seconds and you need to add the "ago" part. This seems to work in my app with ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.18.

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at, include_seconds=false) + " ago" %>
```

Comment: This would kill seconds across everything though, right? I still need seconds displayed, but only when the time is less than 1 minute (ie. "59 seconds ago").

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
time_ago_in_words(post.created_at).split(',').first
```

Which would always display the most significant unit. However, this won't "round" properly; `1 month, 29 days ago` would display as `1 month`, even though you'd probably want it to be `2 months`.