# Rails: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass when calling time_ago_in_words

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some simple code in a partial for one of my views that iterates through a `comments` collection:

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %>
```

returns a `undefined method >' for nil:NilClass` error.

Meanwhile,

```
<%= comment.created_at %>
```

works fine and returns:

`2013-12-25 12:19:53 UTC`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Show us your `time_ago_in_words()` method definition.

Comment: I assumed it was being pulled from the `DateHelpers` library -- the piece of code worked yesterday, then I nested some resources just now, and it's been failing ever since.

Comment: Is it possible that not all of your comments have the `created_at` data?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to put (it isn't english, yes?) your time locals in i18n, like that:

```
"en":
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      about_x_hours:
        # The defaults are "about 1 hour" and "about %{count} hours"
        one: "1 hour"
        other: "%{count} hours"
```

See that: [Rails 3 - time_ago_in_words says "ABOUT 2 hours ago"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801324/rails-3-time-ago-in-words-says-about-2-hours-ago)

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't solve my problem -- could there be anything else?

Comment: @RyanYu do you use locale different than english?

Answer (score 0):

Your comment.created_at is nil - the time_ago_in_words uses the > sign to figure out how to display the output, and it will throw an error if the datetime supplied is nil.